# IE 8 table padding on thead th

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8

I have the following markup within a table

```
<table>

<thead>
 <tr>
   <th width="50" style="width: 50px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">One</th>
   <th>Two</th>
   <th>Three</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

</table>
```

In IE the first column should be 50px wide, but it's actually 63px wide.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out the `width=50` (leave the style one) and see if that changes anything. IE has been known to calculate widths differently, and that might be causing some issues (with the style declaration, you shouldn't need it unless you're supporting ancient browsers, anyway).

Also, what version(s) of IE is having problems? Have you looked in IE's developer tools (F12 for IE8+) to see where it's getting its widths? Finally, it might help if you provide us with  a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or other demo) showing this issue in action, that way we can see if there's something else interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe border, maybe some margins and paddings on other table elements.

edit: Do you have `<!doctype html>` on begining of page? It have to be first in document, there can't be any spaces etc.